# Calibration of a soundcard in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, calibration

I have designed a GUI to calibrate my sound card using MATLAB, I am able to record my input signal. I would like to calibrate my input.

How do I do that?

My GUI should be capable to adapt to different sound cards and get the **dB**V values, hence the Calibration is required. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain to us what "calibration" means in this context.  It is doubtful you mean calibration of equipment (in this case, your sound card) in the traditional sense, since sound cards don't have these kinds of controls.

Comment: Do you have a reference signals with known amplitude? Otherwise I don't know how you want to calibrate.

Answer (score 1):

### A: This is a task from a Metrology, rather than from a programming area

To get the job done, you need a fully-controlled-environment to re-run a defined-input/known-output experiment.

In principle,
your both all your devices and your setup, has to be controlled - i.e.

your **`MIC`**-Input-accoustic/electric converter, while [**dBa**] -> [**V**] conversion is 
"readable" down the cable path, it is not a principally important value per-se,

your **`CABLE`**-wire-path, which shall not be either neglected or forgotten,

your **`SND`**-Card-A/D converter,

your **`AUDIO`-pre-Calibration Sound-Sample**,

your **`TEST`-pre-Calibration Environment**

so as to be able to pre-Calibrate your devices for measurments.

The calibration itself can be achieved right by using the **same** `AUDIO` Sound-Sample in the **same** `TEST` Environment and be that measured / calibrated / by another **<kbd>device</kbd>**, that was certified at a locally recognised reference Authority to have a certain level of precision ( a guarantee that it's readings will not be outside a natl./intl. recognised precision class' envelope from correct/exact values ).

---

**Note:** you may want to pre-Calibrate your **`MIC+SND-A/D`** setup inside your **in-vitro** controlled environment specifically across a wide range of frequencies, so as to avoid frequency-dependent variation of the measurement-conversion path. Thus your pre-Calibration would have sort of Calibration-curve as an input for your further tests to be performed **in-vivo**